# java: Cannot run program "/Android/Sdk/bin/java" (in directory "/cache/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3/compile-server"): error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: java, android-studio

I keep on having an error when I run a java file in android studio. I tried the invalidate caches/ restart but the error keeps persisting.
The code in the file is as follows:

```
import PreviousOrder.PreviousOrder;
import Signup.Signup;
import Login.*;
import Store.*;
import Admin.Admin;
import DateTime.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(new File("src\\Stock.txt"));
       Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(new File("src\\Price.txt"));
       Login l = new Login();
       Signup s = new Signup();
       Store st = new Store();
       Admin adm = new Admin();
       DateTime dt=new DateTime();
       PreviousOrder pre=new PreviousOrder();
       int[] sto = new int[9];
       int[] price = new int[9];
       int cart[]=new int[9];
       int sto1[]=new int[9];
       int bill=0;
       int w = 0, q = -1;
       String ch="50000";String c;
       while (w != 9) {
           sto[w] = Integer.parseInt(scan1.nextLine());
           w++;
       }
       w=0;
       while (w != 9) {
           price[w] = Integer.parseInt(scan2.nextLine());
           w++;
       }
       st.setstock(sto);
       st.setprice(price);
       Details d=new Details();
       do {
           System.out.println("\n1 for LOGIN\n2 for SIGN UP");
           Thread.sleep(1000);
           System.out.print("Enter your choice : ");
           c = scan.next();
           int f = 1, e = 1;
           if (c.equals("1")) {
               while (f != 2) {
                   q = l.check();
                   if (q != -1 && q!=-2) {
                       System.out.println("You are logged in successfully.");
                       System.out.println("Welcome again " + l.name[q]+"\n");
                       dt.DateTime(l.user[q]);
                       f = 2;
                   } else if(q==-2) {
                       System.out.println("Invalid Password or user name. Login Again.");
                       f = 1;
                   } else {
                       System.out.println("User name does not exist.please enter proper user name or sign up first.");
                       System.out.println("\n1 for LOGIN\n2 for SIGN UP");
                       System.out.print("Enter your choice : ");
                       int y=scan.nextInt();
                       if(y==1) {
                           f=1;
                       } else if(y==2) {
                           String u=s.add();
                           System.out.println("Signed up Successfully.Please Login again.");
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           System.out.println("Invalid choice.");
                       }
                   }
               }
               ch=c;
           } else if (c.equals("2")) {
               String u=s.add();
               System.out.println("Signed up Successfully.Please Login again.");
               while (e != 2) {
                   q = l.check();
                   if (q != -1) {
                       System.out.println("You are logged in successfully.");
                       System.out.println("Welcome " + l.name[q]);
                       dt.DateTime(l.user[q]);
                       e = 2;
                   } else {
                       System.out.println("Invalid Password or user name . Login Again.");
                       e = 1;
                   }
               }
               ch=c;
           } else {
               ch="50000";
               System.out.println("Invalid choice.");
           }
       }while(ch.equals("50000"));
       System.out.println("\n\n"+":::::::::USER INFORMATION::::::::::");
       l.UserDetails(q);
       System.out.println("\n \n");
       int wasd=0;
       pre.Order(l.name[q],cart,bill,wasd);
       System.out.println("\n\n");
       if (l.role[q].equals("admin")) {
           String ro="5";
           String rol;
           d.details(sto,price);
           do {
               System.out.println("\n1 for Change in stock \n2 for Change in price \n0 for Exit");
               try {
                   Thread.sleep(1000);
               } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                   System.out.println(e);
               }
               System.out.print("Enter your choice : ");
               rol=scan.next();
               if(rol.equals("1")) {
                   sto=adm.changestock(sto);
                   st.setstock(sto);
               } else if(rol.equals("2")) {
                   price=adm.changeprice(price);
                   st.setprice(price);
               } else if(rol.equals("0")) {
                   ro="0";
               } else {
                   System.out.println("Invalid choice.");
               }
           } while(ro.equals("5"));
       }
       System.out.println("WELCOME TO FASHION HUB");
       d.details(sto,price);
       sto1=sto;
       cart=st.Buy(sto1,price);
       bill=st.Bill(cart,price);
       System.out.println("TOTAL :"+bill);
       int cou=1;
       String h="1",hi;
       do {
           System.out.println("Do you want to change in your cart ?"+"\n"+"1 YES "+"\n"+"2 NO");
           scan.skip("\\n");
           hi=scan.nextLine();
           if(hi.equals("1")) {
               cart=st.Changecart(cart,price,sto1);
               bill=st.Bill(cart,price);
               if(bill!=0) {
                   System.out.println("TOTAL :"+bill);
               }
               h="2";
           } else if(hi.equals("2")) {
               cou=0;
               System.out.println("Please visit Again.");
               h="2";
           } else {
               System.out.println("Invalid choice.");
               h="1";
           }
       }while(h.equals("1"));
       String bu=" ";
       if(bill!=0) {
           String bu1 = "0";
           do {
                   System.out.println("DO YOU WANT TO BUY ? \n 1 YES \n 2 NO");
                   try {
                       Thread.sleep(1000);
                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                       System.out.println(e);
                   }
                   System.out.print("Enter your choice : ");
                   bu = scan.next();
                   if (bu.equals("1")) {
                       for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                           sto[i] = sto1[i] - cart[i];
                       }
                       System.out.println("Your order will be deliver to following address.");
                       System.out.println(l.address[q]);
                       bu1 = "1";
                   } else if (bu.equals("2")) {
                       bu1 = "1";
                   } else {
                       System.out.println("Invalid choice");
                   }
           } while (bu1.equals("0"));
       }
       if (bill == 0 && cou==1) {
           System.out.println("Please visit Again.");
       }
       wasd=1;
       if(bu.equals("1")) {
           pre.Order(l.name[q],cart,bill,wasd);
       }
       st.setstock(sto);
       st.setprice(price);
       FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("src\\Stock.txt");
       for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
           String a=Integer.toString(sto[i]);
           fw.write(a);
           fw.write("\n");
       }
       fw.close();
       FileWriter fw1 = new FileWriter("src\\Price.txt");
       for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
           String a=Integer.toString(price[i]);
           fw1.write(a);
           fw1.write("\n");
       }
       fw1.close();
   }
}
```

The error displayed is:

> java: Cannot run program "/home/astro/Android/Sdk/bin/java" (in directory "/home/astro/.cache/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3/compile-server"): error=2, No such file or directory